# Is it safe to rely on React reusing existing DOM element (e.g. for CSS transitions)?

Tags: reactjs

Consider the following small CSS transition example:

```js
function CssTransitionExample() {
  const [large, setLarge] = useState(false);

  const commonStyle = { border: "1px solid #444", transition: "all 1s" };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setLarge(!large)}>toggle</button>
      {large ? (
        <div
          style={{
            ...commonStyle,
            width: "300px",
            height: "300px",
          }}
        />
      ) : (
        <div
          style={{
            ...commonStyle,
            width: "100px",
            height: "100px",
          }}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

The code works as expected: Clicking the button toggles the visible square between its small and large states with a nice CSS transition.

The reason it works is because React actually re-uses the existing `<div />` in the DOM. If React would instead remove the old `<div />` from the DOM first, followed by attaching a fresh `<div />` the CSS transition wouldn't work.

The question is: Is it safe to use such an approach for transitions, i.e., do the React specs indicate that it will keep this behavior in the foreseeable future, or is the approach relying too much on an implementation detail of React?

Answer (score 1):

Considering the way React updates and re-renders its virtual dom, I'd say it would be a safe approach; but I wouldn't call it the better one.

If you just want to change the inline styles, why don't you use another approach, such as ternary conditionals on the style object? Something like this:

```
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setLarge(!large)}>toggle</button>
        <div
          style={{
            ...commonStyle,
            width: large ? "300px" : "100px",
            height: large ? "300px" : "100px",
          }}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Thanks for your judgement. In the actual real world code motivating the question merging the styles is a bit more awkward. It is more about a visible modal window component vs a hidden modal placeholder component. On first glance it seemed to be more elegant if the window component doesn't have to deal with "hiding itself", but maybe I'll go for that solution (because it would make it more explicit that the placeholder MUST have the same tag).